# Placing a node at a specific distance from the end of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, is it possible to place a node at a specific distance along a path. I know that there is

```
\draw (A) -- node[pos=<f>, above] {$+$} (B);
```

which will place a node at fraction `f` along the path. However, I want to place a node at, say 10pt, before the end of the path from `(A)` to `(B)`. What is the simplest way to do this in TikZ?

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {$A$};
\node [right=of A] (B) {$B$};
\draw [->] (A) -- node[pos=0.9, above] {$+$} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {$A$};
\node [right=of A] (B) {$B$};
\draw [->] (A) -- (B) node[left=10pt, above]  {$+$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind the decorations library dependency, then

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  distance from start/.code={%
    \pgfgetpath\currentpath\pgfprocessround{\currentpath}{\currentpath}%
    \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath{\currentpath}{\currentpath}%
    \pgfmathparse{#1/\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength}\tikzset{pos=\pgfmathresult}},
  distance from end/.code={%
    \pgfgetpath\currentpath\pgfprocessround{\currentpath}{\currentpath}%
    \pgf@decorate@parsesoftpath{\currentpath}{\currentpath}%
    \pgfmathparse{1-(#1/\pgf@decorate@totalpathlength)}\tikzset{pos=\pgfmathresult}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) {$A$};
\node [right=of A] (B) {$B$};
\draw(A) -- node[distance from start=10pt, above] {$+$}
            node[distance from end=5pt, below] {$\times$} (B);
\draw[->, red] (A.east) -- ++(10pt,0); % Test distances
\draw[->, blue] (B.west) -- ++(-5pt,0);
% test curve
\draw[green](A) to[in=45,out=225] 
            node[distance from start=10mm, inner sep=1pt,circle,fill] {}
            node[distance from end=10mm, inner sep=1pt,circle,fill] {} (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice; that should work even on non-straight paths.

Comment: @Rmano ah yes let me add an example

Comment: Thanks. This is the most versatile answer, but I am accepting the other one as it is simpler and meets my needs.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I must grudgingly admit that the main reason that I upvoted it is because the green swoosh is really pretty.

Answer (score 5):

With the `calc` library:

```
\path ($(B)!10pt!(A)$) node [below, red]{$*$};
```

should work (10pt along the `(B)`-`(A)` line).

Comment: In contrast to some of the other answers this works even if the path is not horizontal.

Comment: yes; but I think that @percusse works also for curved path... I think!

Comment: I agree, but this answer looks much easier. And that's why I said "*some of* the other answers".

Answer (score 3):

If the path is on a horizontal line, you can use `xshift`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) {$A$};
        \node [right=of A] (B) {$B$};
        \draw [->] (A) -- (B.west) node[above,xshift=-10pt] {$+$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: Use `(B.west)` instead of `(B)` if you want the new node left of the *end of the path* (as said in your question) and not left of the center of `(B)`.